# Need www. to rewrite rule .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have problem of making my rewrite condition to work.
I have this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.server\.ee$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/server\.ee\/" [R=301,L]
```

It redirects to `https://server.ee`
But i need it to redirect `https://www.server.ee`

How can I manage that?

Tried

```
http\:\/www.\/server\.ee\/
```

But nothing, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Its the same server, it for SEO, to make better URLS

Comment: my redirects work fine, i only need it to add www. part

Answer (score 1):

This code work for me, you may try with this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Make sure you reset your cache before testing this. You will also notice that I've set `R=302`, this makes it a temporary redirect for testing purposes, if you're happy this is working then change it to `R=301` to make it permanent.